# Doctrine Schema error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've added a new bundle and entity to my app. I created a User.orm.xml file and successfully generated the entity from the command line. Now I want to create that additional table in my database.

When I run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get an error. Which leads me to two questions:

1) What would the syntax be to create one table, just the new User entity?

2) What might be causing the error below. I didn't change any of the other orm files. However, I did manually enter a one to many relationship in the entity. Might that be related :

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                                      
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE report CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL':               

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './dbname/#sql-7e5_7' to './dbname/report' (errno: 150)  


  [PDOException]                                                                                                     
dbname  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './dbname/#sql-7e5_7' to './dbname/report' (errno: 150)
```

Two tables, "report" and "reportcolumn"  are related. In the Entity/reportcolumn.php, it's annoted as, but I didn't reflect it in the orm file that initially created the db:

```
    /**
     * @var \Acme\DataBundle\Entity\Report
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\DataBundle\Entity\Report")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reportid", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $reportid;
```

Comment: Use [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things

1. You shouldn't need both the `@ORM\JoinCoumns` annotation and the `@ORM\JoinColumn` annotation - just the `@ORM\JoinColumn` is enough
2. You did *something* to make it (the schema tool) think you changed `report.id` since it's running a `ALTER` statement on that column
3. That SQL error *looks* like the kind you'll get two foreign key columns don't match (i.e., one is `NULL` but the other is `NOT NULL`, or one is `INT` and the other is `BIGINT`). This is not a definitive point but something to check nonetheless. You can check by running a `SHOW CREATE TABLE report` and comparing the definition for the `id` column.
4. Doctrine/Symfony is going to store the Report entity itsef on the associated property, not the id, so I'd rename `Entity::$reportid` to just `Entity::$report`

Comment: I'm using sequelpro to administer my DB. And that's where I had defined a relationship. Removing the relationship at that level allowed the doctrine command to work. And, my queries still return the  expected data. I am a newbie. Perhaps I've misunderstood how Doctrine functions. The relationship need only exist at the entity level?

Comment: You should create/modify your schema with doctrine's schema tool *or* another program (like sequelpro) - not both.  If you're directly editing your schema with sequelpro, you have no need to run doctrine's schema-tool commands.